# Using hibernate @Formula to fetch a collection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a similar db structure. The only difference that I have more tables on the path from A to C entity:

[image]

And I have following mapping for this structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
class A {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String title;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
    @Formula("(select (c.useful_information) from A a " +
            "join B b on a.id = b.a_id " +
            "join C c on b.id = c.b_id " +
            "where a.id = id)")
    private List<String> usefulStuff;
}
```

My aim is to get a list of all useful things from table C in entity A.

But I get syntax errors.

Could you say what's wrong in my example? And maybe you know better way for this purpose?

Comment: 1. missing a space before `where` 2. what is `id`? it is not assigned to any table and not marked as parameter

Comment: It is just example. In my original example there is a space after where. Id is the id of current A entity.

Comment: so basicall `where a.id = a.id`? this would always result in `true` and would therefore be useless

Comment: No, It allows to fetch rows only for current entity. It means that a.id in table matches current entity id

Comment: You get syntax errors, and don't say what they are. The generated SQL is what tells you the problem, so post it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your `@Formula` annotation is the "from A a". The value passed to this annotation is actually SQL, not JPQL.

Thus, if you want to alias the table to reference it elsewhere, you need to rather write `FROM A AS a`.